# How to intercept specific request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nestjs

I'm using `NestJS` and `Angular 2`, both have similar (close) approach to work with `Interceptors`. I would like to find best practice to identify some specific request to do some additional work.

To declare `Interceptor` who will listen some `Controller` (in `NestJS`) I should use this logic:

```
@UseInterceptors(ObjectsInterceptor)
@Controller('objects')
export class ObjectsController {

  @Get()
  async findAll(): Promise<ObjectDto[]> {
    // Request which should be intercepted
    ...
  }

  @Get(':slug')
  async findOne(@Params('slug') slug: string): Promise<ObjectDto> {
    // Request which shouldn't be intercepted 
    ...
  }
}
```

In `Interceptor`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ObjectsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>): Observable<any> {
    // Some logic to detect specific request
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Probably I use wrong way to solve my problem

Comment: I'm almost sure you can put the decorator above the request you want to intercept, not the whole controller

Comment: @MorKadosh That's correct, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put decorator above method instead of class

```js
  @Get()
  @UseInterceptors(ObjectsInterceptor)
  async findAll(): Promise<ObjectDto[]> {
    // Request which should be intercepted
    ...
  }
```